# How to describe Individual using DataProperty in Ontology on GDPR Project

Tags: owl, ontology, protege4

I am trying to describe/develop an Ontology on GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation, source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation).

**I have the following Class hierarchy:**

```
DataProcessingAgreement
PersonalData
  generalPersonalData
  sensitivePersonalData
  semiSensitivePersonalData
System
  CRM
```

**I would like to define the following DataProperties as the `rdf:type generalPersonalData`:**

```
FirstName
LastName
```

Then there are Systems, e.g. a CRM system. CRM stores for example the Firstname and Lastname of a Person. Where **`FirstName`** and **`LastName`** are DataProperties.

I would like to run a SPARQL query asking which `generalPersonalData` are stored by System X or which System stores `generalPersonalData`.

In Protégé i can define this ontology, by using Individuals where I create FirstName, LastName and CRM as an Individual and define the relationship between them e.g. CRM (type:System) stores FirstName (type:generalPersonalData); CRM stores LastName (type:generalPersonalData). But somehow, i not quite sure that is the right way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "define the following DataProperties as the rdf:type generalPersonalData" -> that phrase doesn't make any sense. What do you want to do? Individuals are connected by data properties to literal values.

Comment: "I create FirstName, LastName and CRM as an Individual" -> that's also confusing. You mean, you created an individual and assigned firstName, lastName, etc to it?

Comment: ASKW - im sorry for the confusion. I actually did mean that I created 3 seperate individuals [firstName, lastName and CRM]. What I really want to do is, create an individual and assign firstName and lastName where firstName and lastName are DataProperties. I want to create a Ontology where that is able to tell me "Which systems uses or stores GeneralPersonalData" where Person hasSome generalPersonalData and generalPersonalData is e.g. firstName and lastName

Comment: And what does not work now? Do you have difficulties in defining the data properties in Protege? I don't see any problems with having those properties and writing a SPARQL query that. You can also use the same URI for both as an individual as well as for a data property - this is called punning in OWL 2.

Comment: The problem is, that I am not aware of how to define that the individual "DynamicsCRM365" uses some DataProperty and how to write the SPARQL query for that.

Comment: In Protege? It is just clicking on the individual and add the fact using the data property. Or what is here unclear? I mean it's a graphical editor, that can't be difficult.